# How to find inverse of this equation: $g(x)=e^{3x-1}+\sec{{\pi}x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

**Question:**

How to find inverse of this equation: $g(x)=e^{3x-1}+\sec{{\pi}x}$

*My thoughts on this*

I know that If i was to normally find the inverse you would replace the Y with the X's and solve for y but I dont think that is how it is supposed to work in this problem?

Comment: $x$ belongs to real numbers or integers or ...?

Comment: It is not a 1-1 function . so it has not inverse !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one can quickly see [from a graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ew0njak0tt), the function is not one-to-one, so it doesn't have an inverse function...